# WEBPACK DEV SERVER is not running even though webpack properly generates bundle.js

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I tried to run `webpack-dev-server` in a Gulp task, but even though webpack generates the `bundle.js` properly, `webpack-dev-server` is not running.

When I call 'http://[IP address of the computer]:8080', it says 'This site can't be reached'.

Following is the Gulp task:

```js
import webpack from 'webpack';
import config from './webpack.config';
import WebpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server';

...

gulp.task('serve', () => {
  const compiler = webpack(config);
  const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    quiet: false
  }).listen(8080,  'localhost', (err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

And `webpack.config.js` is:

```js
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client');

export default {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

As a result I am getting the following output:

```js
[10:29:52] Requiring external module babel-register
[10:29:55] Using gulpfile /Volumes/MACDATA/Current_Work/ES6Twitter/project/Hooter/gulpfile.babel.js
[10:29:55] Starting 'serve'...
[10:29:55] Finished 'serve' after 50 ms
Hash: 503283de8850d977b4ec
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 53ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.42 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 29 bytes [rendered]
    [0] ./client/index.jsx 29 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What exactly is the error? The output looks fine to me.

Comment: When I call 'http://[ip]:8080', I just get the server is not responding.

Comment: Did you try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: I was testing with 2 computers connected with LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying `localhost`, but you want to connect from an external machine. In that case, you need to change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`. This makes the dev server accessible on external machines.

Comment: Oh, it works like a charm! Thanks! Even I removed the 'localhost' parameter. The problem was of the domain parameter. Thanks!